# Proving that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{ikb}-e^{ika}}{k}=i\int_a^b\frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}dt$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I deleted my previous question because it was basically totally wrong.

> Let $a,b\in ]0,2\pi[$
>
> Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{ikb}-e^{ika}}{k}=i\int_a^b\frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}dt$

Here is my informal solution.

$\displaystyle \int_a^b\frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}dt=-\int_a^b\frac{1}{1-e^{-it}}dt \stackrel{??}{=} -\int_a^b\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-ikt}dt\stackrel{??}{=} -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_a^b e^{-ikt}dt = -i\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{e^{ikb}-e^{ika}}{k}$

I put some $?$ signs on dubious equalities.

- I doubt that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-e^{-it}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-ikt}dt$

Indeed, for fixed $N$, $\displaystyle \left| \sum_{k=0}^Ne^{-ikt}dt - \frac{1}{1-e^{-it}} \right|=\frac{1}{|1-e^{-it}|}$

- Even if that were true, how do you justify swaping sum and integral here ?

Comment: Your first doubt is the geometric series.  You could replace the exponential term with x and just expand $\frac{1}{1-x}$ if it helps you see it better.  As for swapping sum and integral, it is something you have to be careful about in general, but you can establish that this is safe (what type of convergence does this sum have?).

Comment: Well your sum is a geometric series. So the sum is given by $t_{0}\cdot \frac{1}{1-e^{-it}}$. For the second comment, $\Sigma \int = \int \Sigma$, since the series is uniformly convergent $\forall t \in [a,b]$. This is sufficient.

Comment: @ChrisK You omit that convergence for the geometric-series-formula is granted only when the argument $x$ is such that $|x|<1$. Here the argument is such that $|x|=1$. The computation with $N$ fixed seems to show that it doesn't converge.

Comment: @G.T.R, valid point. This is more nuanced than it initially appears. So this is a case where two wrongs make a right.

Comment: The $\mathrm{LHS}=-\log\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\tan\left(\dfrac{b}{2}\right)}{\tan\left(\dfrac{a}{2}\right)}}\right)$. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you obviously mean the sum from $k=1$ to $\infty$ (the term with $k=0$ is undefined). That said, we have
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{e^{ikb}-e^{ika}}{k}=i\int_a^b\sum_{k=1}^Ne^{ikt}dt
=i\int_a^b e^{it}\frac{1-e^{iNt}}{1-e^{it}}dt.
$$
(For finite sum, no doubt we can swap the sum and the integral and then use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric progression.) Now let $N\to\infty$. We have
$$
\int_a^b e^{it}\frac{e^{iNt}}{1-e^{it}}dt=\frac{1}{iN}\int_a^b\frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}\frac d{dt}(e^{iNt})dt=\frac{1}{iN}\left[\frac{e^{iNt}}{1-e^{it}}\bigg|_a^b-
\int_a^b\frac d{dt}\left(\frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}\right)e^{iNt}dt\right]\xrightarrow{N\to\infty}0,
$$
and hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ikb}-e^{ika}}{k}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{e^{ikb}-e^{ika}}{k}=i\int_a^b \frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}}dt.
$$
We have simultaneously proved that the series converges (conditionally rather than absolutely) and computed the sum.

Comment: Clear and simple, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could also just evaluate both sides using the Maclaurin expansion for $\log(1-x)$ in combination with Abel's theorem.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsConvergenceTheorem.html

Then

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ikb}-e^{ika}}{k} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ikb}}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ika}}{k} \\ &= -\log(1-e^{ib}) +\log(1-e^{ia}) \end{align}$$

While

$$ \begin{align} i  \int_{a}^{b} \frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{it}} \ dt &= \int^{e^{ib}}_{e^{ia}} \frac{du}{1-u} \ du \\ &= -\log(1-e^{ib}) + \log(1-e^{ia}) \end{align}$$

Comment: +1. Fine and quite short thank to Abel and $\tt @Random Variable$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thanks. I must admit that I didn't even know about that theorem until someone mentioned it on another forum a couple of years ago in response to a question I asked.